# How to grep all the data in a specified col from standard output?

Tags: linux, grep

Now i have a standard output which is printed by my program and displayed on the screen. The outputs looks like the following part:

```
Parsing command line string 'InputFile = foreman.qcif'.
Parsing command line string 'NumberReferenceFrames = 1'.
Parsing command line string 'QPISlice = 24'.
Parsing command line string 'QPPSlice = 24'.

------------------------------- JM 11.0 (FRExt) --------------------------------
 Input YUV file                    : foreman.qcif 
 Output H.264 bitstream            : test.264 
 Output YUV file                   : test_rec.yuv 
 YUV Format                        : YUV 4:2:0 
 Frames to be encoded I-P/B        : 150/0
 PicInterlace / MbInterlace        : 0/0
 Transform8x8Mode                  : 1
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Frame  Bit/pic    QP   SnrY    SnrU    SnrV    Time(ms) MET(ms) Frm/Fld Ref  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0000(NVB)     168 
0000(IDR)   34280   24  39.724  41.720  43.998       286       0    FRM    1
0002(P)      7432   24  38.857  41.565  43.829       402      99    FRM    1
0004(P)      8976   24  38.642  41.275  43.698       409      97    FRM    1
0006(P)      8344   24  38.427  41.266  43.515       407      99    FRM    1
0008(P)      8224   24  38.609  41.082  43.524       413      94    FRM    1
0010(P)      7784   24  38.655  40.991  43.235       406      95    FRM    1
0012(P)      7136   24  38.534  40.687  43.273       411      95    FRM    1
0014(P)      6688   24  38.464  40.756  43.146       410      92    FRM    1
0016(P)      7720   24  38.516  40.585  42.851       410      91    FRM    1
0018(P)      6864   24  38.474  40.631  42.958       411     101    FRM    1
0020(P)      8392   24  38.433  40.607  42.646       415      99    FRM    1
0022(P)      9744   24  38.371  40.554  42.498       416      94    FRM    1
0024(P)      8368   24  38.362  40.531  42.380       417      93    FRM    1
0026(P)      7904   24  38.414  40.586  42.415       418      95    FRM    1
0028(P)      8688   24  38.403  40.523  42.366       418      96    FRM    1
0030(P)      9128   24  38.545  40.390  42.661       416      89    FRM    1
0032(P)      9664   24  38.399  40.538  42.740       413      88    FRM    1
0034(P)      8928   24  38.394  40.590  42.852       414      95    FRM    1
0036(P)     10024   24  38.423  40.562  42.697       415      92    FRM    1
0038(P)      9320   24  38.442  40.389  42.689       414      94    FRM    1
0040(P)      7304   24  38.404  40.487  42.884       410      90    FRM    1
0042(P)      8560   24  38.447  40.590  42.673       411      95    FRM    1
```

.......

Now I only need to process the 4th col of SnrY.

So, my question is how to grep this rol and to store them in a data.txt file?

Then I can use plot tool or Matlab to plot the data trends with these data..

Any advices?  Many thanks for your kind help!

Addition:

Since it needs to pick those data from standard output, do I need to use(add) the command provided by you in the command line to make it works during outputs those data
?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk '/FRM/ { print $4 }' < in.txt > data.txt
```

**Note**: I'm just guessing that the interesting lines contain `FRM`. If this is not the case, you must come up with a different way to identify them.

Comment: actually, only SnrY col will be needed in my processing. Thus, I really want to know how to pick just one col of data from this output.:) thanks

Comment: `print $4` picks the column. The more interesting problem is how you pick the interesting *rows*.

Comment: MaiTiano, you misunderstood lutz. He's using the `FRM` to select only data lines (i.e. not the header). The `print $4` is used to pick the column you wanted.

Comment: why don't you use a regex from my answer here instead of /FRM/ which will pick the data from 4th col. this one: /^([^ ]+[ ]+){3}38.4/

Comment: @catwalk Since MaiTiano doesn't specifiy how an interesting row can be positively identified, `FRM` is as good as your regex.

Comment: vote up, good avoidance of regex and clever thinking, i likt it.

Answer (score 3):

`tail -n+17 in.txt | cut -c 23-31`

Comment: Best solution, +1. You may want to throw a `tail -n+16` in there to start at the 16th line (or so) and thus get rid of the header.

Comment: Question, how can this be the best solution? It's assuming that the headers are always at a set size. Not saying it's wrong, im simply asking.

Answer (score 2):

```
./cmd_that_generates_results | awk '/^[0-9]/{print $4}' > data.txt
```

Quick breakdown of *awk* statement:

- */^[0-9]/* : match lines that start with a number
- *{print $4}* : print out fourth column

**(Updated)**: to address question *"Since it needs to pick those data from standard output, do I need to use(add) the command provided by you in the command line to make it works during outputs those data ?"*

You can use the commands given in answers by piping to them the standard output of your program using the pipe (|) command. The results can then be store into "data.txt" using *>*.

see example above. Similar techniques can be used for other solutions in this page.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ ./command | awk 'BEGIN{RS="--+";FS="\n"} END{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i ~ /^[0-9]/){m=split($i,a," ");if(a[4]) print a[4]}}}' 
39.724
38.857
38.642
38.427
38.609
38.655
38.534
38.464
38.516
38.474
38.433
38.371
38.362
38.414
38.403
38.545
38.399
38.394
38.423
38.442
38.404
38.447
```

I am anticipating that the data you want to get

1. need not be after the 16th line, may be after the 17th , or 18th ,etc
2. or that FRM/Fld field  may have different indicators,
3. or the 4th field may not be at the exact character position every time.

So the above just say: set record separator as the line with dashes "-" , so the last record is the whole data you need. then using the newline as field separator (FS="\n") , each field will be each line of data. Split them up with spaces and get element 4 of the splitted line. that will be your desired column.

Answer (score 0):

This will match numbers like 38.4* in the fourth column:
`grep -E '^([^ ]+[ ]+){3}38.4'`

Comment: `0000(IDR)   34280   24  39.724`.